# Select all elements from groups

Tags: mysql, sql

I have next table - `Task(id, type, sessionId, termination, scenario)`
I have a list of `sessionId`.

I would like to select all tasks, which are common for this sessions. Tasks are equals if they have same type, termination and scenario.

Example -

```
| id | type | sessionId | termination | scenario |
  1     A         20        duration      sc1
  2     B         20       invocation     sc1
  3     C         20        duration      sc2
  4     A         21        duration      sc1
  5     B         21       invocation     sc1
```

For `sessionId` list equals (20, 21) - I would like to get next information

```
| id | type | sessionId | termination | scenario |
  1     A         20        duration      sc1
  2     B         20       invocation     sc1
  4     A         21        duration      sc1
  5     B         21       invocation     sc1
```

Task with ids=1,2,4,5 are common for sessions 20 and 21.

I design next query -

```
select l.* from Task l 
inner join(select p.* from Task p 
           where 
                p.sessionId in (20,21) 
           group by 
                  p.type, 
                  p.termination, 
                  p.scenario 
           having 
                  count(p.id)=2)s 
on 
   l.type=s.type 
   and l.scenario=s.scenario 
   and l.termination=s.termination;
```

Is it a best way to get such information? Maybe there is a better query, which contains only one `select` operation and works faster?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the approach.  Find all pairs to type, termination, and Scenario that match all sessions.  Then join back in the `tasks` table to get all information:

```
select t.*
from tasks t join
     (select type, termination, Scenario
      from tasks
      where sessionId in (20, 21)
      group by type, termination, scenario
      having count(distinct sessionId) = 2
     ) tts
     on tts.type = t.type and tts.termiantion = t.termination and tts.scenario = t.scenario
where t.sessionId in (20, 21);
```

You need to change the list and the `2` (if you change the size of the list).

Comment: It is a good decision! But is there a way to not use 2 "select" operations?

Answer (score 0):

My below code does not limit to any particular sub-set of `sessionID`.

```
SELECT t1.* 
FROM Task AS t1 INNER JOIN Task AS t2 ON t1.type = t2.type AND t1.termination = t2.termination AND
                                   t1.scenario = t2.scenario AND t1.sessionid <> t2.sessionid AND
                                   t1.id <> t2.id
ORDER BY t1.id
```

Here's SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/55d7c/9  Feel free to experiment.

Have I somewhat misunderstood your requirements?

Comment: your decision depends on size of sessionId list. It can be more than two sessions)

Comment: My intention was to build a query that does not depend on the number of sessions: look for all that **match** the 3 key fields and **do not match** `id `and `sessionid`. Is it a wrong approach?

Comment: You could add `AND t1.sessionid IN (20, 21) AND t2.sessionid IN (20, 21)`. If you have multiple session ids then you would need to throw in a `GROUP BY` in any case, and it might be that your original query would be faster. (But you should profile first of course.)